# Vue Leaflet incompatible with Vuetify's VDialog

Tags: leaflet, vuetify.js, vue2leaflet

I've been trying to build some sort of GeoJSON editor using Vuetify and Vue Leaflet. The way I do that is by throwing an `LMap` and `VTextInput` onto a `VDialog`. I encounter a problem where a majority of the map tiles show up gray (check out this GitHub issue for more detailed description: https://github.com/vue-leaflet/Vue2Leaflet/issues/157).

I tried all the fixes described in that thread, only to later find out that my `LMap` displays fine when it's neither in a `VDialog` nor `VMenu`. I already tried isolating the editor onto a separate component then wrapping that component in `VDialog`, but it still happens.

Is there a fix or workaround to this problem?

### Update

I found out that the map gets re-rendered properly when browser window is resized.

Comment: What happens if you resize your browser window?

Comment: @ghybs The map re-renders. Properly this time. Updated the question to bring up this finding.